# Prove a sequence tends to $1/2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

[Link to problem + solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmDct.png)

[Definition we were given for a sequence converging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM64g.png)

The red arrows are where I'm confused...
In previous questions, it'd end up with a simpler expression, and I thought I understood how N was chosen, but now I've realised I sadly don't.

My understanding is that you're trying to prove than no matter how small a number you choose, $|a_n-l|$, the difference between an element of the sequence and the sequence's limit, will always be smaller once you've reached a certain point in the sequence ($N$).

In a previous question, $|a_n-l|$ ended up being less than or equal to $3/n$ so it seemed obvious to make $N$ larger than $3/\epsilon$, but the more I try and understand this step, the less I understand it.

And in the question I've linked, why must the whole fraction be put to the power half? Why can't $N$ be chosen so that it is simply larger than $\dfrac{9}{2\epsilon^2}$ ?

Sorry if this is a crappy question, or bad formatting or something I haven't considered.

Many thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest that you visit http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for information on how to format the equations.

Comment: A very kind soul has just done that for me, but I'll be sure to do it myself next time!

Comment: You do the root because you want an inequality for $n^2$.  $9/2n^2$ will be less than the epsilon so you need $n^2$  greater than $\dfrac{9}{2\epsilon^2}$.  If n *squared* is larger, then n not squared must be larger than a square root. a value meaning n needs to be greater than a square root.